# MyBatis call stored function with returning value and out parameter

Tags: java, oracle, mybatis

I'm trying to call a function like this:

```
PCK_BEE.FUN_FOO(A IN VARCHAR2, B OUT T_CURSOR) RETURN VARCHAR2;
--
TYPE T_CURSOR IS REF CURSOR;
--
TYPE R_DEP  IS RECORD (P_CODE VARCHAR2(3),  P_DESC   VARCHAR2(30));
```

On MyBatis I created an Object:

```
public class LovPrc {
   private List<ProcedureTypeLov> lov;
   private String error;

   // Getters and Setters
}
```

ProcedureTypeLov:

```
public class ProcedureTypeLov {
   private String code;
   private String description;

   // Getters and Setters
}
```

Mapper:

```
<select id="lovDep" resultType="LovPrc" parameterType="map" 
           statementType="CALLABLE">
    { #{error, mode=OUT, jdbcType=VARCHAR} = call 
        PCK_BEE.FUN_FOO(#{A, mode=IN,
                        #{lov, jdbcType=CURSOR, 
                              mode=OUT, resultMap=LovPrc, javaType=java.sql.ResultSet})}
</select>
```

POJO is returning the object but I'm getting it as null.

How I should call this type of function and return it on the POJO? Can't change it to a PROCEDURE with both parameters as OUT

Answer (score 1):

Handled this yet, this is how I make it work:

```
<select id="lovDep" parameterType="LovPrc" statementType="CALLABLE">
{ #{error,jdbcType=VARCHAR,mode=OUT} = call PCK_BEE.FUN_FOO(#{A, mode=IN, jdbcType=VARCHAR},
                                                            #{lov, jdbcType=CURSOR, resultMap=MapLov, mode=OUT})}
</select>

<resultMap id="MapLov" type="ProcedureTypeLov">
     <result column="A (name of the column returned by CURSOR)" property="a"/>
</resultMap>
```

LovPrc as parameter Object for the call and out Object to handle the response.